# Adding data frame to Oracle table using RODBC

Tags: r, rodbc

I am a beginner in R so please excuse any stupid or obvious question.
I am trying to append a dataframe(tab) to a pre-existing table(APPS.EMPLOYEE) in Oracle using RODBC. I tried the following code:

> dbWriteTable(con, name = APPS.EMPLOYEE, value = tab, append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE)

But every time I execute this command am getting an error:
Warning: Error in .jcall: object 'APPS.EMPLOYEE' not found.

Kindly advice. Thank you.

Comment: I think this is RODBCDBI (not RODBC). Also... why the tag MySQL if you're trying to write into an Oracle table?

Comment: I have removed the tag MySQL